# npm install and npm install --force are not working when I try to update my project's node version via nvm

Tags: python, node.js, cordova, npm

I have an Ionic 3 Cordova 10 project that I need to update to Cordova 12. Since the project was created using Node 12, and Cordova 12 required Node 16, I use nvm to install the LTS of v16 with all the global dependencies:

`nvm install 16 --reinstall-packages-from=12`

But when I do an `npm install` or `npm install --force`, I get this long error:

[image: Error when trying to npm install --force]

I do have Python2 installed. The default is Python3.

This happens no matter what node version I try to install, and continues to happen even after I delete node_modules and package-lock.json

I found no solution to this online. Not even changing to Python2 via:

`npm config set python /usr/bin/python2.7`

I want to be able to use node 16 in my project for compatibility with Cordova 12.

Comment: `npm` is the `node package manager` for nodejs.  it has nothing to do with python.

Comment: `nodejs` and `python` are different languages.

Comment: Yeah, I know. That's why I don't understand what it is mentioned in the error.